# How to go to the next found result when using the less command on a log file in Linux?

Tags: less, linux-terminal

I have a log file where I can use `less` on the file where I know how to go to the bottom of the log file with a <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and then use `?` to query in the text file.

What I don't know how to do is when I go to the bottom of the log file and find my first error or what I ever searching for with `?` how I do get to the next one? From the bottom up I am hoping to go up and up and up on each error in the log file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the manual, [`man less`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html):

```
       n      Repeat previous search, for N-th line containing the last
              pattern.  If the previous search was modified by ^N, the
              search is made for the N-th line NOT containing the
              pattern.  If the previous search was modified by ^E, the
              search continues in the next (or previous) file if not
              satisfied in the current file.  If the previous search was
              modified by ^R, the search is done without using regular
              expressions.  There is no effect if the previous search
              was modified by ^F or ^K.

       N      Repeat previous search, but in the reverse direction.
```

Comment: Just beat me :)

Comment: When having `less` in use (i.e. when reading a text) a simple press on `?` will show quite a bit of help. No need to bring up the Man. ;-)